# Xcode image occupying whole tableView instead of cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

So I am creating a prototype which I will use later.

I have a table view with one cell, then I will make the whole table populate several cells (that is working)

My problem is, the image on my cell, instead of occupying the cell to occupies the whole table view as follows

Any ideas?

Thanks

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEvRr.png)

[Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9DyB.png)

---

EDIT

repo: https://bitbucket.org/eduardoreecreate/coderswag-ios

Comment: Add some code or zip a sample project for more help

Comment: what parts do you wish to see?

Comment: Please provide an example to illustrate your problem

Comment: @Xco15etb if possible can u share the project. If not share the view controller and tableviewcell class

Comment: rak, the illustration is on the question. Ok Ankit, i am going to commit one second

Comment: added @AnkitKumarGupta

Comment: It could be due to the autoresizing (the picture that is taking up whole page might have autoresizing on and others dont) or have you tried changing the order of which the assets are displayed on top of each other

Comment: Check cell height in story board by clicking the cell and going to size inspector. If that did not solve, 
try implementing heightForRowAt(at: indexpath) delegate function and giving it a constant height.

Comment: my repo is on the question.

Comment: height is 150 just checked

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the image view's content type to AspectFit and ClipToBounds to true

Answer (score 0):

Implement `heightForRowAt` `UITableView`'s delegate

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 150 
   // Customize or write a logic as per your requirement like for 1/4 of screen UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height / 4
}
```

If you select the cell in IB, then the Size Inspector shows Row Height at the top (with a "custom" checkbox), but if you select the whole table view the Size Inspector shows Row Height at the top there too (no "custom" in this case). The table view setting is used for dynamic cells. (Not sure if it's intentional)

[image]

Comment: It works thanks, but could you explain me why it doesn't work without it? On my storyboard I gave the cell those 150?

Comment: On dynamic cells, rowHeight set on the UITableView always overrides the individual cells' rowHeight.

But on static cells, rowHeight set on individual cells can override UITableView's.

Not sure if it's a bug, Apple might be intentionally doing this?

Comment: Upvote if your problem was solved when you have enough points.

Comment: mine is a dynamic so I need to change it on he UITableView, is that what you mean?

Comment: Correct :) Then you won't need to implement this delegate method

Answer (score 0):

By default, an image view under the influence of auto layout wants to be the size of the image. Your image is big. Therefore the image view is big. Therefore the cell itself is big, because you are *autosizing the cell height* to match the height of its contents.

The simple solution is: don't do that! Before you put the image into the cell, munge it in code so that it is the correct height. It is very foolish to put a huge image into a small table cell in any case, or any small image view, because you're still wasting all that memory. Always try to crop / shrink the image before putting it into the interface.

More elaborately, you can give the image view an absolute height constraint to keep it from growing beyond a certain height. Or, as you've already been told, don't use automatic cell height; set the cell height to some absolute value by implementing `heightForRow`.

Comment: I see.... so on my storyboard wether I drag it down or up (my cell) it is only visual?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You have to determine the _real_ cell height at runtime by your settings on the table, the cell contents, and/or the table delegate.

Comment: makes so much more sense now